# Como mostrar o tempo desse contador na barra de título da janela?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Segue o arquivo do cronômetro:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nkejbjjsx1vv6g2/timer-stopwatch-jquery-2242015.zip?dl=0

Ele mostra o tempo no input, mas eu queria que ele mostrasse também na barra de título do navegador, mesmo minimizado eu quero que o tempo seja mostrado no título da janela de forma dinâmica (atualizada de tempo em tempo, no caso, a cada segundo)

Acho que tenho que fazer algo como:

document.title = Tempo do cronômetro;

Mas como pego o tempo que é mostrado no input?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icone.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Cronômetro</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <div   style="background: #00662e; color: white; padding: 20px; text-align: center;"> <strong> Cronômetro </strong> </div>
    <p><br/><br/><br/></p>
    <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input name="timer" class="form-control timer" placeholder="0 sec" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <button class="btn btn-success start-timer-btn">Iniciar</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success resume-timer-btn hidden">Retornar</button>
                    <button class="btn pause-timer-btn hidden">Pausar</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger remove-timer-btn hidden">Resetar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->

    <script src="timer.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function(){
            var hasTimer = false;
            // Init timer start
            $('.start-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
                hasTimer = true;
                $('.timer').timer({
                    editable: true
                });
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
                $('.pause-timer-btn, .remove-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
            });

            // Init timer resume    
            $('.resume-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
                $('.timer').timer('resume');
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
                $('.pause-timer-btn, .remove-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
            });


            // Init timer pause
            $('.pause-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
                $('.timer').timer('pause');
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
                $('.resume-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
            });

            // Remove timer
            $('.remove-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
                hasTimer = false;
                $('.timer').timer('remove');
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
                $('.start-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
                $('.pause-timer-btn, .resume-timer-btn').addClass('hidden');
            });

            // Additional focus event for this demo
            $('.timer').on('focus', function() {
                if(hasTimer) {
                    $('.pause-timer-btn').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.resume-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });

            // Additional blur event for this demo
            $('.timer').on('blur', function() {
                if(hasTimer) {
                    $('.pause-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('.resume-timer-btn').addClass('hidden');
                }
            });
    })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a pergunta? O que pretendes e o que está a falhar...

Comment: Este código é de um cronômetro progressivo, segue o arquivo: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nkejbjjsx1vv6g2/timer-stopwatch-jquery-2242015.zip?dl=0

Ele mostra o tempo no input, mas eu queria que ele mostrasse também na barra de título do navegador, mesmo minimizado eu quero que o tempo seja mostrado no título da janela de forma dinâmica (atualizada de tempo em tempo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta colocar um set interval a cada 1 segundo pegando o valor que esta no input timer.

```
setInterval(function(){ document.title = $('.timer').val(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Pronto! Resolvido.